# Cocos2d js How to word- wrap ccLabel

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I have created a label and tried to wrap it.
Its wrapping when space appears in the text but it also wrapping when comma(,) appears in the text.

I do not want to wrap when comma appears.

Any help.

Code -

```
    var label = new cc.LabelTTF("Get 100% Welcome Bonus upto Rs. 1,000 on your first deposit.", "Arial", 30);
    label.setPosition(cc.p(this.width / 2, this.height / 2));
    label.setScale(0.5);
    label.setColor(cc.color(255, 0, 0));
    label._setBoundingWidth(520);
    this.addChild(label, 1000);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution to this problem

Cocos2d use regex to wrap word. So we need to add comma in regex.

```
cc.LabelTTF._lastWordRex = /([a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüßéèçàùêâîôû]+|\S)$/;
cc.LabelTTF._lastEnglish = /[a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüßéèçàùêâîôû]+$/;
cc.LabelTTF._firsrEnglish = /^[a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüßéèçàùêâîôû]/;
```

To

```
cc.LabelTTF._lastWordRex = /([a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüßéèçàùêâîôû,]+|\S)$/;
cc.LabelTTF._lastEnglish = /[a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüßéèçàùêâîôû,]+$/;
cc.LabelTTF._firsrEnglish = /^[a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüßéèçàùêâîôû,]/;
```

Just put it in main.js